# A computer or computers

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "a computer" or "computers" in my sentence?

1."A computer has become very important in the modern world."

Comment: 'The computer has...',  or 'computers have...'

Comment: Do you know the difference between singular and plural?

Comment: @Antonia A, this makes at least five low-quality questions today about the same piece of writing. This website is not an essay review platform. Please ask questions that fit the profile for this site, or ask them somewhere better suited for the purpose, like [HiNative](https://hinative.com/en-US)

Comment: For the others, see: [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298241/it-becomes-cheaper-or-it-is-becoming-cheaper), 
[here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298238/does-it-get-larger-or-smaller), 
[here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298236/i-am-not-having-any-luck) and 
[here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298229/the-before-education-and-computer-revolution)

Comment: Another site you can try for longer pieces than just one sentence is [italki](https://www.italki.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is possible but they mean slightly different things.  In your sentence you probably want **computers**.

In general, the plural, **computers**, means "computers in general; all computers".

**A computer** means "one computer", so if I read "A computer has become important", I immediately think "One particular computer became important?
Which computer?"  But it could be used to imply "*having* a computer" in some contexts, like "A computer is useful for students who are taking this class."

**The computer** can also mean "computers, as a general rule".  This is the kind of usage we see in "The tiger is a dangerous animal."