# The before education and computer revolution

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is "the" required before "computer" and "education system"?

> The computer revolution changed the education system.

I mean they have become very important.

Comment: The words you really want to look at here are *revolution* and *system*, because "computer" and "education" are just modifying those words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "the" before "computer revolution" because you are specifying one out of many revolutions. Similarly, you need "the" before "education system" because you are specifying one out of many systems.

Perhaps you feel that **stylistically** the sentence given is verbose and bland. Style is a matter of opinion, but I agree with you if that is your opinion. Moreover, it may not even express your true argument.

> Computers revolutionized education

is more concise and more forceful and may express better what you want to say.