# Does it get larger or smaller

Tags: present-tense

Should I use  present simple or progressive in my sentence?

"Scientists disagree about some important facts. Does the universe get larger or smaller?"

Comment: Antonia, you've asked almost exactly the same question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298241/it-becomes-cheaper-or-it-is-becoming-cheaper). If you do a bit of research about the functions of present simple and present continuous, you'll be able to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say, "Does it get larger or smaller?", the natural question that brings up in my mind is, "Does it get larger or smaller when you do what?" The phrasing implies at a particular time or under particular circumstances.

If you mean, as I would guess you probably mean, something that is happening as a continuing process, you should say, "Is it getting larger or smaller?" You could say, "Does it continually get larger or smaller?" I'm sure there are many other ways to word it.

(Side note: I thought it was pretty well accepted that the universe is expanding. I've never heard scientists debate that assertion. But if you or whoever wrote that sentence is championing some alternative theory, this is an English language site and not an astronomy site so I suppose that's all tangential.)