# It becomes cheaper Or it is becoming cheaper

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Should I use present simple or progressive with "all the time"?
"Technology becomes cheaper all the time."

Comment: The difference is the same as always between present simple and present continuous. Do you understand the function of those two forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Technology becomes cheaper" is presented as a general statement of truth, or what is sometimes called a ["law" or "rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_laws)—referring not to a legal construct but a descriptor of *the way things are*.

"Technology is becoming cheaper" is a specific observation about a specific point in time (*i.e.* the present) and does not claim to be correct for all time.

Which one you use depends on what you want to say.